# e.preventDefault is not a function while passing other params

Tags: reactjs

actually am trying to passing params with event to my function.
Here when user upload image then i want to fire SendMessage function by passing fileURL as Params. but am getting e.preventDefault  not a function

here is my upload code

```
UploadTask.then(snap => {
      console.log(snap.ref.getDownloadURL()); //getting download link
      this.SendMessage(snap.ref.getDownloadURL())// passing download link as param to my SendMessage function
    });
```

SendMessage:

```
 SendMessage = (e,fileUrl = null) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.message) {
      this.setState({ error: false });
      const ref = firebase.database();
      ref
        .ref("messages")
        .child(this.props.channel.id)
        .push()
        .set({
          content: this.state.message, //what i want here if am getting FileUrl then set this content to fileUrl otherwise this.state.message
          timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          User: {
            id: this.props.currentUser.uid,
            displayName: this.props.currentUser.displayName
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ message: "" });
          console.log("Message Send");
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: true });
    }
  };
```

```
 <form className="form" onSubmit={(e) => {this.SendMessage(e)}}>
```

Comment: your code should, work, have the same code except your requirement specific logic here, and it works.. https://codesandbox.io/embed/beautiful-taussig-188ew

if you post a codesandbox i could take a look

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the original event args to `SendMessage()`.  Try this,

```
this.SendMessage(snap, snap.ref.getDownloadURL());
```

or

```
UploadTask.then(snap => {
      snap.preventDefault();       
      console.log(snap.ref.getDownloadURL()); //getting download link
      this.SendMessage(snap.ref.getDownloadURL())// passing download link as param to my 
    });

SendMessage = (fileUrl = null) => { //Do not pass e
    //e.preventDefault();
    <Rest of the method>
}
```

Comment: this is not working because what ii have in my app that there is send button and upload image button when i click send button then i want to prevent default behavior and when somone upload media then i want to fire sendmessage function with fileUrl param to set message to fileUrl

Answer (score 0):

In your upload code you're calling `this.SendMessage(snap.ref.getDownloadURL())` where you pass a url as an event. Change it to `this.SendMessage({}, snap.ref.getDownloadURL())` to make it work. Considering that event looks like an optional param here, maybe you'd put it second after the url.